# domain name pointing to local server between multiple developers

Tags: networking, dns, internal

We are a few web developers and currently edit our host file to point domain names to the local web server but this is becoming hard as number of clients are increasing and we need to continuously change each host file of computers.

What do you think is the best possible solution for us, use a proxy server or a dns server, and could you possibly tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DNS server, or use mDNS, on your LAN.  Then an administrator can simply add an A or CNAME entry to the zone, and all the computers on the LAN will see that record.